# How to push to github from netbeans without local branch

Tags: git, netbeans, github, repository

I have received a github project url from a friend of mine who gave me r/w access to his repo. I downloaded the stuff with the "download as zip" button on github, worked on the project, but now when in neatbeans i do right click/remote/push, i enter repo informations, then it asks me to choose a local branch which i don't have because I downloaded manually the files.

So I created a local branch with the same name of the only branch of the project I can see on github, but when I do "push", nothing changes on the repo. My versions simply don't get uploaded.

Any clue ? I am new to git so sorry if I ask something which may seem obvious.
THanks

Comment: Did you commit your changes on the local branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Backup your changes.
2. (assuming git is installed correctly) checkout the project from GitHub using [`git clone <url>`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) (now you should be on a master branch. if there is only one branch that doesn't matter, if there are other branches be sure to use the right one with `git checkout`)
3. Then try to copy your changes (files from backup) on top of the files retrieved by `git clone`.
4. within the repo's root directory run `git status` and check if there are files need to be staged to the index [(`git add`)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)
5. if everything is staged to the index run [`git commit -a -m "some message"`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)
6. finally run `git push`

Using GitHub you maybe require a ssh key or use the HTTP connection.
**BUT** this is of course a bad solution because you treat the idea of SCM with contempt. In the future you should first connect to a repository, make your changes commit and push them. Only then you are able to do fine-grained commits and revert them if something was wrong. Commiting a large set of changes is not the right way!

Answer (score 6):

I have had this problem myself.

The solution I found was to make changes to the code, commit the changes and then push.

In short:

1. Make changes to the code
2. Commit changes (under team menu)
3. Push changes (under team->remote)

Hope this helps!